# Postgresql: Split columns into rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
gid | cat1 | cat2 | some_value
-------------------------------
 1  |  A   | 100  |    I 
 2  |  B   | 200  |    II
 3  |  C   | 300  |    III
 4  |  D   | 400  |    IV
```

I would like to convert this table into something like this, i.e. convert a column value into a row value:

```
gid | category | value | some_value
-----------------------------------
 1  |   cat1   |   A   |     I
 1  |   cat2   |  100  |     I
 2  |   cat1   |   B   |     II
 2  |   cat2   |  200  |     II
... |   ...    |  ...  |     ...
```

Is this possible in Postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Union`:

```
Select gid, 'cat1' as category, cat1 as value, some_value from t
union all
Select gid, 'cat2' as category, cast(cat2 as varchar(100)) as value, some_value from t
order by gid
```

here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aff83/4) for it.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I get `column "gid" does not exist` for the first line. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have column `gid` in your table? did you changed table name from `t` to your actual table name?

Comment: Yes and yes - I actually built the table from my example. If I add `from t` in the first row it works, but I get `UNION types character varying and integer cannot be matched` in line 3

Comment: Oh, the cast should be for `cat2`, I changed it